# grep for a word and if it matches get the content between parentheses

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have many files which generally looks like below.

```
    { 
      key1:value1, 
      key2:value4 
    }, 
    { 
       key1:value1, 
       key2:value4 
    }, 
    { 
       key3:value3,
       key5:value5 
    }
```

I would like to search for a key, say key5. If key5 is present, then I
 would like to print everything under the parentheses. In this case, it will be

```
    { 
       key3:value3,
       key5:value5 
    }
```

I don't want to do after context and before context with grep because the keys present in the parentheses may vary. And the content inside parentheses is not in one line.

Comment: If this is JSON you should really treat it as JSON and not text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use gnu-awk with a custom record separator for this:

```
awk -v RS='{[^}]+}' 'RT ~ /key5/ {print RT}' file
{
   key3:value3,
   key5:value5
}
```

`RT` represents matched text by `RS` pattern.

Another way to do this is using gnu-grep:

```
grep -zoP '{[^}]*?key5[^}]*}' file
{
   key3:value3,
   key5:value5
}
```

**EDIT:** You can use `perl` also:

```
perl -0ne 'print $1  . "\n"if /({[^}]*?key5[^}]*})/' file
{
   key3:value3,
   key5:value5
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:** Here is a BSD awk solution:

```
awk -v RS='{' '/key5/{printf "%s", RS $0}' file
{
   key3:value3,
   key5:value5
}
```

Comment: I'm trying these commands on Mac and these doesnt seem to work

Comment: gnu commands are also BASH but OSX don't ship them by default. Anyway perl should work on OSX as BSD commands don't search spanning multiple lines unless you use a loop.

Comment: Check my updated answer for a BSD (OSX) awk solution.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer, but, just for fun, a `sed` solution:

```
sed -n 'H;/{/h;/}/{g;/key5/p}' file
```

- Append the current line to the **H**old space
- If line matches `/{/`, replace the contents of the **h**old space with it
- If line matches `/}/`, **g**et the hold space, replacing the current line. If the replacement matches `/key5/`, **p**rint it (printing everything accumulated in the hold space, from the starting `{` to the ending `}`
- Do not output the line unless explicitly printed (`-n` flag)

As with any `sed` script making use of the hold space, you're probably better off using the `awk` solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/{/h;//!H;/}/!d;x;/key5/p' file
```

If a line contains `{` replace the hold space with that line. Otherwise append the line to the hold space. Delete all lines except those containg a `}` in which case swap to the hold space and print it if the required string is present.

N.B. the `-n` switch invokes seds grep-like nature and suppresses the normal print out of every line.

Comment: Looks POSIX compatible to me. What makes it GNU sed?